# hadoop h2o r, h2o.importHDFS, error

Tags: r, hadoop, h2o

Using R-hadoop which is hosted at 172.16.53.31:8787, I am trying to import file from HDFS to H2O which is hosted at 172.16.53.31:54331 (originally 54321).

This error happened. Any idea?

[image: error]

Or any advices?

Please and thanks.

Sincerely,

Newb

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to read the screenshot error pasted into the screen, but it looks like InvalidProtocolBufferException.

In this case, it looks like the "hdfs://172.16.53.31:" is not well-formed.

Try "hdfs://172.16.53.31" with no port.
Or try adding the correct port for your Hadoop installation.

If you give a totally wrong port, the thing you point to won't speak protobuf.

This error can also happen when the Hadoop client version is too different from the Hadoop server version.  (Note that if you start H2O with the 'hadoop jar' method, the correct Hadoop libraries are put on the client classpath by 'hadoop jar'.)

If you start H2O using 'hadoop jar' then you generally pick up the name node from the environment, and can just give "hdfs:///path/to/file.csv" with no name node specified.

Answer (score 1):

I did have the same problem.

Try to add the 9000 port number to your hdfs path.

Something like this:

```
hdfs://<ip>:9000/<dataPath>/
```